# How to write custom form and code for Joomla login?

Tags: development, joomla-3.3.x, login

I'm a beginner in Joomla. I don't want to customize or use modules like BTlogin or default login module in Joomla. I want to create fresh login module with minimum code, I don't know how the passwords are encrypted so please some one help me.

Comment: The default login module is pretty slim.  What in particular are you trying to achieve with your login module?

Answer (score 1):

You would be best off using the default Login module provided with Joomla. You will find this one to have minimal code as options are rather limited. Joomla 3.x uses `Bycrypt` as the password encryption method as supposed to `md5 + salt` in Joomla 2.5.

Just so that you know, you do not have to create your own module as the Login module comes shipped with Joomla, so all you have to do is enable it and set it's position in the Module Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to worry about the encryption methods, because you can use the built in authentication library to handle it for you.

IE:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$username = $app->input->get('username', '', 'STRING');
$password = $app->input->get('password', '', 'STRING');

$result = $app->login(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```